# Create GeoJSON polyline with elevation from a shapefile

Tags: arcmap, leaflet, geojson, gps, gpx

Here is my situation: I have volunteers using smartphones to collect bike trails. These GPX files are a good start, but they need editing due to canopy cover, etc. I export these to shapefiles and edit to match the actual trails where I can see them with the latest ortho imagery, get rid of spikes, other issues. However, the edited shapefile have lost the elevation (and time) data from the original GPX file. I want to export this shapefile as a GeoJSON to show it in a web map. The resulting geometry should have z values like this:

```
"geometry": {
  "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        -83.43572,
        39.1932,
        272.9
      ],
```

Is there a way to take the polyline shapefile, add elevation information, and export that to GeoJSON. Maybe first to a point, then to a GeoJSON linestring? If there is a geojson editor that may work as well.

Comment: You have an ArcMap tag but make no mention of that software in your question. How is it involved?

Comment: I suppose you have ArcMap if you edit your point shapefile. What about the [Features to JSON](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/features-to-json.htm) tool?

Comment: If you're in ArcMap, making shapefiles using the GPX to Features tool, note that shapefile output does not support full time fields. Push your output to FileGDB instead. Not sure why you're losing elevation though?